# Sencha Touch launch signal to jQuery

Tags: jquery, sencha-touch

I want to use a jQuery plugin in my Sencha Touch application.

The jQuery plugin should be initialized at startup, but only after Sencha Touch is finished filling the DOM with its magic.

This is because the plugin scans the DOM for certain elements and alters them.

If I use `$(document).Ready()`, the `<body>` tag is still untouched by Sencha Touch, even when I place the Sencha Touch code above the jQuery code.

What is the best practice way to handle this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tap into EXT's own onReady event.

```
Ext.setup({
    // system-generated set-up code
    onReady: function() {
        // write your setup code here
    }
});
```

Comment: you sir, are my hero. But I don't really understand what u mean with the "system generated set-up code" comment. I just copy pasted your code under my entire "var App = new Ext.Application({ ... })" code and it worked. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: If you started with Designer instead of coding from scratch, you'll find that Designer may have put something in there.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `painted` event of your view:

```
config: {
  ...

  listeners:{
    painted: function(){
     // all the DOM are in place
    }           
  }
}
```